# Posting token in JS Form with Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

Hi I'm trying to modify a Posting form generating with JS to add the CSRF token,

Code as below:

```
var defaults = module.exports = {

    name: 'staplesbmincart',

    parent: (typeof document !== 'undefined') ? document.body : null,

    action: 'checkout.html',

    target: '',

    duration: 30,

    template: '<%var items = cart.items();var settings = cart.settings();var hasItems = !!items.length;var priceFormat = { format: true, currency: cart.settings("currency_code") };var totalFormat = { format: true, showCode: true };%><form method="post" class="<% if (!hasItems) { %>sbmincart-empty<% } %>" action="<%= config.action %>" target="<%= config.target %>">    <button type="button" class="sbmincart-closer">&times;</button>    <ul>        <% for (var i= 0, idx = i + 1, len = items.length; i < len; i++, idx++) { %>        <li class="sbmincart-item">            <div class="sbmincart-details-name">                <a class="sbmincart-name" href="<%= items[i].get(" href") %>"><%= items[i].get("googles_item") %></a>                <ul class="sbmincart-attributes">                    <% if (items[i].get("item_number")) { %>                    <li>                        <%= items[i].get("item_number") %>                        <input type="hidden" name="item_number_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get(" item_number") %>" />                    </li>                    <% } %>                    <% if (items[i].discount()) { %>                    <li>                        <%= config.strings.discount %> <%= items[i].discount(priceFormat) %>                        <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].discount() %>" />                    </li>                    <% } %>                    <% for (var options = items[i].options(), j = 0, len2 = options.length; j < len2; j++) { %>                        <li>                            <%= options[j].key %>: <%= options[j].value %>                            <input type="hidden" name="on<%= j %>_<%= idx %>" value="<%= options[j].key %>" />                            <input type="hidden" name="os<%= j %>_<%= idx %>" value="<%= options[j].value %>" />                        </li>                    <% } %>                </ul>            </div>            <div class="sbmincart-details-quantity">                <input class="sbmincart-quantity" data-sbmincart-idx="<%= i %>" name="quantity_<%= idx %>" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" value="<%= items[i].get(" quantity") %>" autocomplete="off" />            </div>            <div class="sbmincart-details-remove">                <button type="button" class="sbmincart-remove" data-sbmincart-idx="<%= i %>">&times;</button>            </div>            <div class="sbmincart-details-price">                <span class="sbmincart-price"><%= items[i].total(priceFormat) %></span>            </div>            <input type="hidden" name="googles_item_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get(" googles_item") %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="amount_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].amount() %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="shipping_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get(" shipping") %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="shipping2_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get(" shipping2") %>" />        </li>        <% } %>    </ul>    <div class="sbmincart-footer">        <% if (hasItems) { %>            <div class="sbmincart-subtotal">                <%= config.strings.subtotal %> <%= cart.total(totalFormat) %>            </div>            <button class="sbmincart-submit" type="submit" data-sbmincart-alt="<%= config.strings.buttonAlt %>"><%- config.strings.button %></button>        <% } else { %>            <p class="sbmincart-empty-text"><%= config.strings.empty %></p>        <% } %>    </div>    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />    <% for (var key in settings) { %>        <input type="hidden" name="<%= key %>" value="<%= settings[key] %>" />    <% } %></form>',

    styles: '',

    strings: {
        button: 'Check Out',
        subtotal: 'Subtotal:',
        discount: 'Discount:',
        empty: 'Your shopping cart is empty'
    }

};
```

Any help please.

Comment: anyone can help me adding the csrf token plz

Comment: show us your `ajax` request.